# Adding multiple style in Javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a javascript function to change a button style when a button click.

HTML

```
<button id="pause" class="pause" onclick="event_click_startpause(this);">Pause</button>
```

Javascript

```
window.event_click_startpause = function(btn) {
    if (interval === null) {
        start();
        btn.innerText = 'pause';
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#c1580b";
        btn.style.box-shadow= "0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B"
    }
}
```

Here I want to add another style for the button. For that I added this also

```
btn.style.box-shadow= "0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B"
```

Isn't it possible to add multiple styles in this function? So how can I fix this.

Comment: In DOM (and Javascript), the property names are *camelCase* (`.style.boxShadow`). Only in CSS they are *kebab-case*. ツ

Comment: Do you have Jquery in your Project?

Comment: No there isn't Jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add as many styles as possible but the names of styles are in camelCase not the kebab-case as you are using right now for `box-shadow`.

Therefore you have two options, either use `btn.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B"`

Or if you want to use kebab-case you can use `style.cssText` like this:

```
btn.style.cssText = "box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B";
```

Note that you can specify multiple css rules at the same time using the technique mentioned above therefore you can do this:

```
btn.style.cssText = "box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B; background-color: #c1580b";
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
function event_click_startpause(btn) {
  interval = null;
  if (interval === null) {
    // start();
    btn.innerText = 'pause';
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "#c1580b";
    btn.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B"
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="pause" class="pause" onclick="event_click_startpause(this);">Pause</button>
```

Working Fine!

Answer (score 2):

**Easy To Understand Solution**

```js
function event_click_startpause() {
    document.getElementById("pause").setAttribute(
       "style", "background-color:#c1580b;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #173B0B;");
}
```

```html
<button id="pause" class="pause" onclick="event_click_startpause();">Pause</button>
```